# How to make the Windows 10 clipping tool save the screenshots locally?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, snipping-tool, windows-10-1809

The clipping tool was overhauled in the Windows 10 1809 update (October 2018), [the screenshots are saved to clipboard only](https://www.howtogeek.com/352290/using-windows-10s-new-screenshot-tool-clips-and-annotations/). Being able to capture with various methods by using the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key only (alternatively <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) without  third-party software makes this feature highly beneficial, but the clipboard limits the potential. For instance, I don't think that the Stack Exchange image uploader can handle any clipboard data.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Pasting to some image editor such as Paint, then exporting isn't an acceptable answer.

Comment: You know `WinKey+Prt Sc` saves a full-screen screenshot to your "Screenshots" folder, right?

Comment: @KeithMiller: Essentially always I want to select an area of the screen. This hotkey also hasn't worked for me for quite some time, but that's another topic.

Comment: If you can stand third-party software, you may want to check out [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1319897/automatically-save-a-snipped-screenshot-to-disk/1323713#1323713).