# Can I get Windows to automatically save my screenshots?

Tags: windows, windows-10, screenshot, windows-10-v2004

Various [tips](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-default-screenshots-folder-location-windows) [sites](https://windowsreport.com/create-save-screenshots-windows-10/#3) indicate that screenshots taken by pressing, for example, WIN-SHIFT-S or PrintScreen are supposed to show up in a `Screenshots` subdirectory of the `Pictures` directory in my home folder.  However, on my quite new installation of Windows 10, they don't get saved there and are just kept in the clipboard, so I have to paste them into e.g. Paint in order to save them somewhere.

Is there a way to tell Windows to automatically save them?  I'm used to MacOS behaviour where it saves screenshots using names containing timestamps.

Comment: For Windows 10 free download and install gadwin screen capture utility. You can use the `prt sc` key and save to any folder you want. Although it is customizable I do not like the way they name files.

Comment: "Is there a way to tell Windows to automatically save them? " No

Comment: Similar question>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1319897/automatically-save-a-snipped-screenshot-to-disk?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically save a snipped screenshot to disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1319897/automatically-save-a-snipped-screenshot-to-disk)

Comment: Yeah, that's the same question, guessed I missed it in my search.  Cheers!

Comment: That does happen to answer my question, even though the question is not actually about how to save screenshots but about how to take screenshots of a section of the screen.