# How to make Windows Snipping Tool always save image instead of putting it in clipboard

Tags: windows, clipboard, screenshot

I take many screenshots on my Windows 10 laptop.

I sometimes use Windows Snipping Tool (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> which opens the little bar at the top and you can take a snip of the window, whole screen or custom selected part of it. Now the problem is that it only saves the picture in clipboard. To save it as an image somewhere, people paste it in paint and save the paint file, which is too much to do.

I tried using the Windows Game Bar Capture (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and then capture button) settings, but that only allows whole screen to be snipped.

So how to make snip tool save your picture somewhere? Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Windows does not have a built-in tool to do what you describe.  Snipping Tool (legacy) nor Snip & Snetch behave the way you want it to.  You will have to use a third-party application to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I use SnagIt and it offers all you need in terms of saving and is a better editing tool. Consider that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically save a snipped screenshot to disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1319897/automatically-save-a-snipped-screenshot-to-disk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to have the built-in Windows Snip & Sketch (Based on your mention of the Win+Shift+S shortcut, I assume you mean this and not the older Snipping Tool) automatically save your images. However there are a few things you can do instead of opening Paint and pasting/saving there:

1. After you snip an area, you should get a notification popup in the bottom-right corner of your screen, like the below image. Clicking this will open a Snip & Sketch window where you can save the image directly.

[image: notification]

2. Use the [Paste Into File](https://github.com/EslaMx7/PasteIntoFile) utility. This will add a right-click context menu item that will save your clipboard contents to a file.

[image]
[image]

3. Use a 3rd-party screenshot program, such as [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) or [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/). Both will allow you to automatically save screenshots to a folder, along with many other features.

Answer (score 12):

Snip and Sketch stores your screen clips automatically.

After upgrading from Windows 10 version 1909 to 20H2, screenclippinghost.exe (the process behind Snip and Sketch) now stores images here:

`%LocalAppData%\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`

Rather than here:
`%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`

Comment: This continues to work on Windows 11. Adding `%LocalAppData%\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip` to Quick Access is very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Some third-party products have the capability to automatically save the screenshots
to a folder.

For example, see the open-source
[greenshot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot).

More screenshot tools can be found in the article
[Best Free Screen Capture Tool](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-capture-tool.htm),
and some may also have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Use SnagIt.  Several features in SnagIt allow capture / snips / text to be saved in several formats.  You can set up keystrokes called Hotkeys for snips with a selection of your preferences for "effects", "share" and snip "regions".   "Save to clipboard", "Preview in SnagIt Editor" can also be designated.

Answer (score 0):

The Snip & Sketch tool copies to the clipboard but will also save the image to a temp file. The temp file of the image is stored at following locations:

C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip

or

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip

For more details, please refer to the following thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/aia21t/snip_sketch/elt5ajt/

If you don't want to go above locations to find captured screenshot, simply press Windows key + PrtScr to take screenshot.

Now either open MS Paint program and press Ctrl+V. Edit and save your screenshot.

Or open File Explorer and locate Pictures library. Under Screenshots folder, you'll find the captured screenshot.

Comment: Looks like that Reddit thread was from April 2019 (1903?).  Siljuberg's answer gives the correct location now for 2004 / 20H2.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this issue.

Couldn't find a way to set a preference in "Snipping Tool" settings, however there is an easy enough workaround:

## Workaround:

After doing a snip:

1. Click the pop-up "***Snip saved to clipboard. Select here to mark up and share the image***".
2. Click the little "floppy disk" icon which then gives you the ability to save it as a file to a specified location

Tested in Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

As a function:

```
function Snip-Copy {
  cp ( Get-ChildItem $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip\ | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 ) ${env:USERPROFILE}\Pictures\Screenshots\ }
```

Comment: It would help others if you explained the components

Comment: Of course... As Siljuberg explained above this is where Snips get saved. This function copies the newest snip to the `Pictures\Screenshots` directory. However, I will add now that I discovered that this method lessens the size than the originals. I lack knowing why.