# Autosave [WinKey + Shift + S] screen shots

Tags: windows, windows-10, screenshot

Is there any way to autosave [<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>] screenshot?

I know there is the possibility to autosave the entire screenshot (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>) but I can't find this option for snipped screenshots.

Comment: Snip 'n Sketch (WinKey Shift S) saves first to clipboard (I do not think you can change this), then you can open it (notification area) and save it wherever you want it to be. That works.

Comment: Ye, I know about that but it's really burdensome when I need to take many screen shots. On Ubuntu, it's effortless - just `Shift` + `Print Screen` with `Ctrl` if you don't want to save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to autosave <kbd>**Win ⊞**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**S**</kbd> screenshots?

As of this writing, I believe the answer is (natively) no.

However, you might be able to use a third-party tool like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) to accomplish something similar (see this [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1319897/automatically-save-a-snipped-screenshot-to-disk/1323713#1323713) for a general overview of the process for automatically saving snipped screenshots).

Note that while the answer linked above references <kbd>**Win ⊞**</kbd> + <kbd>**Print Screen**</kbd>, Greenshot comes with the option to define custom hotkeys:

[image: Greenshot Custom Hotkey Options]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll accept this answer until someone post a Windows build-in solution.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you. =) I hope you find a native solution.